# Vite Dev server not available on localhost

Tags: vue.js, build, vite

I have built a chrome extension using Vite and Vue. I'm also using CRXJS and ExtensionPay. When I run the unpacked extension in Brave with `npm run` dev everything works.
If I try to run `npm run preview` I get this error:

```
Cannot connect to the Vite Dev Server on http://localhost:3000

Double-check that Vite is working and reload the extension.

This page will close when the extension reloads.
```

If I run

```
npx vite
```

in the output folder I get

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

because of this line:

```
"use strict";const Xm=require("./Extpay.js-J2Sy7LH6.js");/**
```

What am I doing wrong here? I have spent days trying to fix this without any progress.

Vite config:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite"
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue"
import { crx } from "@crxjs/vite-plugin"
import manifest from "./manifest.json"
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs'
import mergePermissions from "./mergePermissions"

// import { resolve } from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [vue(), crx({ manifest })],
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            input: "Extpay.js",
            output: {
                dir: 'output',
                format: 'cjs'
            },
            plugins: [commonjs({
                    strictRequires: true,
                }), 
                mergePermissions({ permissions: ["offscreen"] }) 
            ],
        },
        modulePreload: false,
    },
    server: {
        host:"localhost",
        port: 3000,
        strictPort: true,
        hmr: {
            port: 3000,
        },
    },
    preview: {
        port: 8000,
        strictPort: true,
    },
});
```

Manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "MyExtension",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "action": { 
        "default_popup": "index.html"
         
    },
    "icons": {
        "48": "hat48.png",
        "128": "witch-hat.png"
      },
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js",
        "scripts": [ "Extpay.js" ],
        "type": "module"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "tabCapture",
        "offscreen",
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "storage"
    ],
    "host_permissions": [
        "https://extensionpay.com/*"
    ],
    "commands": { 
        "showcontentdialog": { 
            "suggested_key": { 
                "default": "Ctrl+Shift+Y" 
            }, 
        "description": "show content dialog" 
        } 
    }
  }
```

**UPDATE: PROBLEM FIXED**

I couldn't get ExtPay to work by installing from NPM.
I had copied the Extpay.js from github into my own project. That file is using CommonJS. For some reason I wasn't able to get vite to compile it to ESM. Then I noticed in the file there's a comment that says not to use it in your project, so I guess that's why.

With this ESM version of ExtPay.js from /dist I got it working:
https://github.com/Glench/ExtPay/blob/main/dist/ExtPay.module.js

Here's my current rollup config:

```
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs'
import mergePermissions from "./mergePermissions"
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';

export default {
    rollupOptions: {
        input: "src/main.js",
        output: {
            dir: "output",
            format: "cjs",
        },
        plugins: [
            nodeResolve(),
            commonjs(),
            mergePermissions({ permissions: ["offscreen"] }),
        ],
    },
};
```

Comment: Find what is calling the require for this and add it to your `optimizeDeps: { include: [] }` property in your vite config. `require` is not recognized by vite (and is also not recognized in chrome extensions), so you need to solve for this.